# Get teamId in message extension handler

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

When developing a message extension for Microsoft Teams, is it possible to retrieve the ID of a team where the user is invoking the message extension command without first adding the bot to that team?

I can do this when the bot is added to the team manually based on `TeamsInfo.getTeamDetails()`, however, I don't really need (or want) to add the bot to the team for my goal. All I need is the channel ID (which is available from the context/conversation) and the ID of the underlying team. Retrieving the team details without the bot being added beforehand errors with "The bot is not part of the conversation roster".

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the ChannelData property on the Activity class, that should give what you need. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-basics?tabs=dotnet#teams-channel-data).

Here's an example of the underlying payload, for interest:

`"channelData": { "eventType": "channelCreated", "tenant": { "id": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47" }, "channel": { "id": "19:693ecdb923ac4458a5c23661b505fc84@thread.skype", "name": "My New Channel" }, "team": { "id": "19:693ecdb923ac4458a5c23661b505fc84@thread.skype" } }`

Comment: Well, `channelData.team.id` seems to be identical with `channelData.channel.id` which seems off to me and doesn't work with the Microsoft Graph API. What I'm really looking for would be `aadGroupId` from the team details, but I can only retrieve those when the bot is added to the team.

Comment: If you're in the General channel, then yes, they will match - "General" channel basically -is- the "Team".

Comment: Ah, okay, interestingly enough the docs say `team.id` would be "GUID for the channel", so it's not really the ID for the team but rather the ID of the general channel of a team. Do you know if it's possible to retrieve the `aadGroupId` for the team from that point in order to reference the team to the Graph API? Again, without adding the bot to the team, if that's possible

Comment: Yeah, it's quite crazy that this Id is NOT the AadGroupId, and I think it's quite tricky to get. I don't have a good idea offhand, other than querying the users graph (e.g. JoinedTeams endpoint, and iterating through that, which is hardly ideal). I'd suggest ask this as a separate question and see what others respond if they have a good idea

Answer (score 0):

we had the same trouble with the Team documentation and APIs.
However for that specific case, we found a solution that may work for you. I will say is more a hack than a solution. But it worked on my use case. It will only work on messages with attachments.

When the context is received in a message, the message contains an attachments array. Each attachment object has a contentUrl. Inside that url is the mailNickname for the group. That mailNickname field represents a readeable unique id. The format is something like **sites/{mailNickname}/General**.
from there you can retrieve the field and use the Groups Graph API.

With a query like this one:
**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(mailNickname, 'themailNicknameFromcontenturl')**
You will get the group full information, including the aadGroupId

In general, is a nightmare to work with Teams documentation. Hope this hack helps you.