# Get unencrypted Teams chat ID from personal chat in message extension

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is it possible to retrieve the ID of a personal / one-on-one chat (between two users, not between the user and a bot) from inside a message extension in an unencrypted format so that it's usable with the Graph API?

I'm pretty sure I already know the answer because why else would it be encrypted in the first place? The thing is, this is really inconsistent as you can retrieve the plain chat ID for group chats or even the plain ID of channels.

All calls to `TeamsInfo` or the `BotFrameworkAdapter` in that regard fail with `Error: The bot is not part of the conversation roster`. I presume they'd only work when the bot is part of the conversation (which is not possible for personal chats).

This way my message extension can't work in personal chats which wouldn't make sense to users. Anybody know a workaround?

I've had the same problem with fetching the team ID (specifically the AAD Group ID of the team) for channels (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64896124/get-teamid-in-message-extension-handler)) which I bypassed by fetching all teams/channels of a user from the Graph API and matching based on channel ID. However, I can't find a similar workaround for personal chats as there's literally no info on the chat available other than the encrypted chat ID as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the ID is not 'encrypted', but it might be 'encoded' (i.e. follow a set algorithm) to get a unique chat id.

Either way, similar to the last answer, you can get what you need via the Graph (Beta endpoint). See the [List Chats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) endpoint and the [Get Chat Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) endpoint.

Comment: Encoded would me it's reversable, but it isn't afaik. These endpoints don't give me what I need since they'd require the (not encrypted/encoded) chat ID - and I don't have that from the activity

Comment: You can use List Chats to get the chats themselves, like you're doing in for Teams+Channels - the ID should match what you're getting on the Teams context I think, that's coming in to your message extension

Comment: It is not the same ID, as I've said, for personal chats the activity only contains the ID in an encrypted/encoded format - this only works for groupChat and channel conversations, that's the point

Comment: @nilo, Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Yes, I think there is no solution at this point, Microsoft probably would have to update it's bot service

Comment: What you are trying to do with chat Id in your Message Extension? [Get Chat Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#response-1) returns the chat id and chat type as well if it is personal

Comment: I want to be able to reference the chat towards the Graph API based on the information accessible when invoking a message extension. However, the message extension gets only the type (personal) and an encrypted chatId.

Answer (score 0):

You can [fetch conversationChatId for your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp#-retrieve-the-conversation-chatid) by using Graph API.

**Steps:**

1. [Get the teamsAppId for your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp#-get-the-teamsappid-for-your-app)
2. [Determine whether your bot is currently installed for a message recipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp#-determine-whether-your-bot-is-currently-installed-for-a-message-recipient)
3. [Retrieve the conversation chatId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp#-retrieve-the-conversation-chatid)

Please follow the steps given in the documentation and let us know if you are facing any issues.

Comment: Step two of your solution requires the userId of the recipient user, but you don't get that from the bot context in personal chats in the first place. Your steps are also meant for receiving the ID of a chat between a user and the bot for issuing a proactive bot message. So, it's not the chat between two users where the message extension was invoked in the first place. Besides not solving the problem, this would require excessive permissions.

Comment: 1. You can get the user AAD Id from Bot Payload in activity.From.Id field. 
2. Another option would be to prompt user to [JustInTime Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/messaging-extension-v3/create-extensions?tabs=typescript#request-to-install-your-conversational-bot) of App. Check [this sample](https://github.com/Trinetra-MSFT/89.teams-just-in-time-installation/blob/master/JustInTimeInstallation/Bots/JustInTimeInstallationBot.cs#L51).

Comment: "JustInTime Installation" solution will not work if the bot is not part of the conversation roster. To make it simple the bot cannot send anything to the chat if he has not been installed on it